# Json rpc: ускорение

Tags: json, php

Здравствуйте. 
Есть 2 сервера. 
Один в США, а другой в России=) 
Есть 20 json запросов на сервер в Россию с сервера в США. 
Запросы все идентичные и выглядят так.

```
$b = newjsonRPCClient('http://zzzzz:xxx@11.11.1.1:123/');
    $a = $b->zzz($p);
    $c = $b->qqq($p);
    $d = $b->www($p);
```

Вот таких же запросов еще 16. 
Получают данные с разных портов и разных пакетов. 
То есть вариант в 1 подключение не подходит. 
Можно хоть как то ускорить ?+)

Comment: можно попробовать сделать запросы в параллель. Это иногда может помочь (если к примеру, на посылку запроса и получение ответа тратиться больше времени, чем собственно на обработку)

Answer (score 1):

мутно задан вопрос, а ускорить даже логически нельзя, ты 20 раз подключаешься к серверу, и ждешь от него ответы. ускорить можно, если ты перепишешь сервер в России, и сделаешь для себя один запрос, чтобы он все выводил, что тебе необходимо.